# Доступ к файлам вне папки сайта из скрипта php

Tags: php, apache2, доступ, php.ini, selinux

Никак не могу найти нормальной информации по настройкам прав доступа для скрипта `php`, может кто ткнет слепцу где надо искать?

**Суть**: Имеется тикетная система и удаленная CRM система.

Задача стоит в том, что бы регистрация в тикетной системе была доступна только тем, кто есть в этой CRM. Выгрузка данных происходит с использованием API к CRM системе.

И все было хорошо, однако заказчик пожелал что бы данные пользователей лежали в отдельной папке внутри файловой системы. В итоге был создан файл конфигурации, где прописываются пути к файлу с выгруженной информацией (выгружать во время регистрации не вариант, так как выгрузка и парсинг данных происходит за 10-20 секунд, что слишком долго)

В результате столкнулся с проблемой доступа к этому файлу и файлу конфигурации. Python получает доступ без проблем, но из `php` скрипта сделать это не удается. Ковырял настройки `httpd`, права доступа на файл и проходящие папки, настройки `SELinux`. Ничего не помогает, `php` исправно возвращает `false` при попытки открытия файла (если файлы располагаются в любом месте внутри корневой папки сайта все отлично)

Сервер на `linux CentOS`, используется `php 5.6` (более новые версии, к сожалению использовать не получится из-за ограничений заказчика) и `apache 2.2` файл настройки располагается в `/etc/file.conf`, а файл с данными по пути `/var/site/user.json`

Куда копать? Заранее спасибо, если кто откликнется.

Comment: Копайте в сторону open_basedir заодно смотрите логи сервера апача или энджина на ошибки в доступе, это вам укажет явную проблему, также не мешало бы нам знать, какую панель управления вы используйте

Comment: Скорее всего речь идет о опен бэйс, так как сам столкнулся с тойже проблемой, думаю это и есть и ваша

Comment: симлинк на файл сделайте внутрь папки сайта и все

Comment: 10-20 секунд это небось выгрузка по всем пользователям? по конкретным параметрам не запросить что ли? по емаилу или еще чего?

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Думаю open_basedir это именно то что нужно Панели управления нет, сайт хоститься на серверес прямым доступом. Симлинк тоже не одобряется заказчиком, но спасибо за совет. К сожалению, проверка происходит по коду из CRM, почта и логин может отличатся, так как лицо с которым заключается сделка и лицо регистрирующиеся на хелпдеске будут различные, а API удаленной CRM не поддерживает фильтр выгрузки по настраиваемым полям. Плюс имеется ограничение на количество запросов в секунду и количество возвращаемых объектов. Можно сократить до ~10секунд, но это ничего не меняет.